# Why are my variables not updating in a php mysqli for-loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli

I am trying to sort a single table (of 10k+ rows) into two separate tables, but seem to be running into a nonsense error that I can't figure out. When i comment out the mysqli insert statements, the variables are printing out correctly and updating as they should. I can see all of the data with the correct keys and values even when looping through all the values in the table.

When I add in the insert statement and place it in a mysqli_query, however, I am suddenly getting tons of mysqli errors saying that there are suddenly duplicate primary keys, but as per the previous tests, there are no duplicates. Other times, it seems to only loop once and then stop (or loop the correct amount of times, but doing nothing each time. I have printed out the mysql statements and was able to see that they were all correct before attempting the query, and yet it still causes issues when actually running. The code in its entirety is included below, but I cannot figure out what the issue is for the life of me.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM originalTable ORDER BY port LIMIT 20";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$num_Rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $num_Rows."<br/>";

// gets data for each row in the table

for($i=0; $i<$num_Rows; $i++){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $ID = $row["ID"];
    echo $ID."<br/>";
    $IP = $row["IP"];
    echo $IP."<br/>";
    $port = $row["port"];
    echo $port."<br/>";
    $running = $row["running"];
    echo $running."<br/>";
    $afk = $row["afk"];
    echo $afk."<br/>";
    $gamemode = $row["gamemode"];
    echo $gamemode."<br/>";
    $maxplayers = $row["maxplayers"];
    echo $maxplayers."<br/>";
    $spawnprotection = $row["spawnprotection"];
    echo $spawnprotection."<br/>";
    $whitelist = $row["whitelist"];
    echo $whitelist."<br/>";
    $enablequery = $row["enablequery"];
    echo $enablequery."<br/>";
    $enablercon = $row["enablercon"];
    echo $enablercon."<br/>";
    $rconpassword = $row["rconpassword"];
    echo $rconpassword."<br/>";
    $motd = $row["motd"];
    echo $motd."<br/>";
    $announceachieve = $row["announceplayerachievements"];
    $allowflight = $row["allowflight"];
    $spawnanimals = $row["spawnanimals"];
    $spawnmobs = $row["spawnmobs"];
    $forcegamemode = $row["forcegamemode"];
    $hardcore = $row["hardcore"];
    $pvp = $row["pvp"];
    $difficulty = $row["difficulty"];
    $generatorsettings = $row["generatorsettings"];
    $levelname = $row["levelname"];
    $levelseed = $row["levelseed"];
    $leveltype = $row["leveltype"];
    $autosave = $row["autosave"];

    if($IP == $server1){
        $server = "server1table";
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO server1table (id, ip, port, running, afk, gamemode, maxplayers, spawnprotection,
              whitelist, enablequery, enablercon, rconpassword, motd, announceplayerachievements,
              allowflight, spawnanimals, spawnmobs, forcegamemode, hardcore, pvp, difficulty,
              generatorsettings, levelname, levelseed, leveltype, autosave) VALUES ('$ID', '$IP',
              '$port', '$running', '$afk', '$gamemode', '$maxplayers', '$spawnprotection', '$whitelist',
              '$enablequery', '$enablercon', '$rconpassword', '$motd', '$announceachieve', '$allowflight', '$spawnanimals',
              '$spawnmobs', '$forcegamemode', '$hardcore', '$pvp', '$difficulty', '$generatorsettings', '$levelname',
              '$levelseed', '$leveltype', '$autosave')";
        echo $sql1;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
        echo "Server 1<br/>";
        if($result){
            echo "Success?";
        }
        else{
            echo "Failure = " . $conn->error;
        }
    } else if ($IP == $Server2){
        $server = "server2table";
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO server2table (id, ip, port, running, afk, gamemode, maxplayers, spawnprotection,
              whitelist, enablequery, enablercon, rconpassword, motd, announceplayerachievements,
              allowflight, spawnanimals, spawnmobs, forcegamemode, hardcore, pvp, difficulty,
              generatorsettings, levelname, levelseed, leveltype, autosave) VALUES ('$ID', '$IP',
              '$port', '$running', '$afk', '$gamemode', '$maxplayers', '$spawnprotection', '$whitelist',
              '$enablequery', '$enablercon', '$rconpassword', '$motd', '$announceachieve', '$allowflight', '$spawnanimals',
              '$spawnmobs', '$forcegamemode', '$hardcore', '$pvp', '$difficulty', '$generatorsettings', '$levelname',
              '$levelseed', '$leveltype', '$autosave')";
        echo $sql2;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        echo "Server 2<br/>";
        if($result){
            echo "Success?";
        }
        else{
            echo "Failure = " . $conn->error;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: The ID in the table above is not the table ID field or primary key. It represents the ID of the player. The port is the primary key of the table

Clarification: In one iteration of this code, it sent everything to server 1 with no issues, but it totally ignored server 2. I have since tested and ensured that the split (if statement) worked as intended, and it prints the correct server name and sets $sql to the intended value (as it prints out). It will only move the first column of the table and then it sets everything else to blank and the ID to 0 and sends a bunch of duplicate primary errors.

Comment: **warning** you are asking for sql injection attacks here!

Comment: This function will only be run once and once only. It is designed to migrate a database from one main database to two seperate ones based on the IP. It is not publicly available and as such could not have that issue

Comment: what if the data in there has some single quotes? that will break your queries

Comment: Not necessarily, depends where the original data came from. As long it wasn't from user entry it should be okay. This looks like internal data. Otherwise, yes, it would need to be scrubbed with prepare or mysqli::escape_string (I believe mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated but I still have heaps of code with it in).

Comment: I considered that might be the case, but the data is all simple words, numbers, or blanks.

Comment: your question is quite hard to understand, and it will not solve your problem, but just for note: the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is iterator function so for i to 0..n is not necessary, `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))` is more more grammatically correct

Comment: suggestion: store the source id value in different field in second database, let mysql to autoincrement its primary key

Comment: also you can `extract($row)` in your case (variables are same as array keys) instead of that looooong assignments
http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Why are you doing this in PHP in the first place? Why not just `INSERT INTO server1table (id, ip, port, ...) SELECT id, ip, port, ... FROM originalTable WHERE ip = '$server1'`?

Comment: You're using `$server1` in the first `if` and `$Server2` in the second `if`. Did you really name one variable all lowercase and the other with an initial capital letter?

Comment: Those are placeholders for the actual table names. In the actual code, the names are copy/pasted correctly and follow similar rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be inserting the IDs, that might be where you're fighting with possibly the table primary keys and auto_increment. Just remove the id from the insert and it should be fine. Depending upon how you've set up the table structure. Generally you shouldn't need to preserve the IDs, that's just there for uniqueness and indexing housekeeping etc.

Comment: The ID is badly named in this case. It is actually the player ID and not the ID of the table. The primary key of the tables is the port, and must be migrated as well.

Comment: Can you just do it as dump/restore then delete the unneeded rows from each? Or do you not have CLI or phpMyAdmin access? Another way would be to turn off auto increment on the primary keys until you've run the script.